# UML Message to Actor?

Tags: uml, actor, sequence-diagram

I have a question about UML sequence diagrams. I've always been taught by my professors that there cannot be a message from a class directly to an actor, that messages can only be sent to a boundary class (interface) in which the actor can then interact with. Is this correct or wrong?

[image: example of what I've been taught]

Usually I see something quite different when searching online, like so:

[image: example of what I've been seeing]

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. The dotted message is a return message and can simply be read as the answer/result of a primary actor-sent message. You can **not** create a "normal" message to an actor in first place, though.